# StreamWriter doesn't respond

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that edits a few lines in a text file, to a user set value, from a textbox.

At least, before I even bothered to start with this value setting. I can't even edit the file. What's wrong with this code? I actually tried more examples, but none of them worked.

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //login button
{
    username = textBox1.Text;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\TEST.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Last User:" +username );
    }
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: try to flush the writer, by calling writer.flush() before exit the application

Comment: Standard users do not have edit rights to the root of the C:\ drive by default. Are you swallowing an exception?

Comment: Your code worked for me.  I am running as admin on Windows 7.

Comment: @user2511414: `Dispose` call from `using` block is flushing the stream.

Comment: Your code is fine, your permissions probably are not.

Comment: File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\TEST.txt", new [] { string.Format("Last User: {0}", "PJx") });

Comment: @jimmy_keen thanks, I really didn't know :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An educated guess.

Try to write your file in a different folder.
The C disk root is write protected by Operating system

for example

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\TEMP\\TEST.txt", true))
```

or read the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum to find an appropriate folder where your application could store its data.

```
string appFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string privateAppFolder = Path.Combine(appFolder, "MyAppFolder");
if(!Directory.Exists(privateAppFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(privateAppFolder);
string myFile = Path.Combine(privateAppFolder, "Test.txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myFile, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Last User:" +username );
}
```

Comment: I had this issue when I first started fiddling with that class too.

Comment: Yes, usually it is write protected, of course it could be changed but it is not a good practice. I think it is so from XP but at that time everyone was an administrator and so none noticed.

Comment: @user2511414 - It varies with the security settings on the system, but either way it's generally bad practice to write to C:\.

Comment: C:\ has been read-only to Standard users since Windows 2000. Really. It's just that for so long so many Windows users have been running as Administrator. The new UAC policies in Vista/7/8 are finally putting an end to this.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Hehe.
Is there a way, to point it to AppData?

Comment: @ValtersTomsons `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn As my Vulcan friend says: "Fascinating"